# How to print the keys here?

Tags: python, dictionary

I gave some values & keys in a dictionary & showed the value of two keys present here.

```
def save_user_1(**user):
    return user["id"], user["mail"]

print(save_user_1(id = 1, name = "john", mail = "save_user_1@gmail.com"))
```

**Output :** (1, 'save_user_1@gmail.com')

1.Why does it show the output as a tuple here?

2.How can I get the values of keys here ?(The oppposite of what showed in the output)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. To get a list as output, use brackets : `return [user["id"], user["mail"]]`
2. You can try `user.keys()` to get the dictionary keys, or `user.items()` to get both keys and values :

```
def save_user_1(**user):
    print('user keys', user.keys())
    for key, value in user.items():
        print("key =", key, ", value =", value)
    return user["id"], user["mail"]

print(save_user_1(id = 1, name = "john", mail = "save_user_1@gmail.com"))
```

output :

```
user keys dict_keys(['id', 'name', 'mail'])
key = id , value = 1
key = name , value = john
key = mail , value = save_user_1@gmail.com
(1, 'save_user_1@gmail.com')
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Because `user["id"], user["mail"]` is a tuple, same as `(user["id"], user["mail"])`.
2. You are getting the values for the keys `'id'` and `'mail'`. If you want the keys (I'm not sure why you would) you could `return [k for k in ('id', 'mail') if k in user]`.

Answer (score 0):

When you do `return user["id"], user["mail"]` you are telling python to return a tuple. Could you add to your question what kind of output you would like from `print`?